# Replacing new vector after it gets empty on Python

Tags: python, arrays, vector, matrix-multiplication

Hi have an original vector, I would like to put the first 3 elements into new vector, do some math and then get new elements after the math. Put those new elements into a new vector, delete the original first 3 elements from original vector and repeat this exact procedure until the original vector is empty.

This is what I have done so far

```
OR=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

new=OR[0:3]

while (True):

    tran=-2*c_[new]

    OR= delete(OR, [0,1,2])

    new=OR[0:3]

    
    if (OR==[]):

        break
```

However it is not working out properly, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `c_` is in your code, but regardless since numpy arrays are not dynamic, you can't remove or add elements to them. Deleting elements creates a new array without those elements, which is not optimal. I think you should either use a python deque which has fast pop methods for removing one element from the front/end, or just iterate over the original numpy array, for example like this:

```
def modify_array(arr):
    # your code for modifying the array here

result = []
original_array = np.arange(1, 10)

for idx in range(0, len(original_array), 3):
    result.append(modify_array(original_array[idx:idx+3]))

result = np.concatenate(result)
```